# How to get plain text from highlight.js element?

Tags: javascript, html, highlight, highlight.js

I use highlight.js this way:

```
<div class="ex1" contenteditable="true">
   <pre>
      <code id="script_code" class="pgsql"></code>
   </pre>
</div>
```

User can edit the code. When user wants to save changes I need to get plain text.

When I get it:

```
var pscriptText = document.getElementById(divCodeView).innerHTML;
```

I see the tags. How to get the plain text?

Comment: i don't see any element with id  `divCodeView` in posted code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of innerHTML:

```
var pscriptText = document.getElementById(divCodeView).textContent;
```

Comment: Thanx, exactly what I need!